# iOS 4 and iOS 5 SDK's in xCode 4.5.1 on Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, ios5, osx-mountain-lion

I have migrated to Mountain Lion OS version 10.8.2. Since mountain lion, installed xCode 4.5.1. Now I only get the development target iOS 6. However, I have to deploy both version sdk's (iOS 5 & iOS 4) in xCode 4.5.1.

**How can I have both iOS 5 and iOS 4 SDK's (simulators) in xCode4.5.1?**

Please help.

Thanks,
Rubini.S

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need to do..

- Download XCode 4.3.* dmg from developer.apple.com and install the application
- Double click on the dmg file
- Right-click on the XCode icon and choose 'Show Package Contents'
- Navigate to directory /Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
- Drag the directory iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk to your desktop
- Open terminal session and execute following commands

  cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

  sudo mv $HOME/Desktop/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk .

  sudo chmod -R root:wheel iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
- Restart XCode
- Now if you launch the Simulator, you should be able to switch to see the option for iOS 5.1 under Hardware
- If you also want to test on iOS5, copy the relevant SDKs from the iPhoneOS.platform directory

Comment: Is that supposed to be `chown` and since nothing else in my .sdk directory is owned by `root:wheel` I assume I should just be changing it to match everything else.

Comment: Great answer. Any suggestions on getting iOS 4 for Xcode in Mountain Lon?